# How to remove curly line on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I use tesseract ocr to recognize the text on the image. I have a problem with images that have curly lines. I tried various method such as threshold, gaussian filter, extract by color.. but I cannot remove it.  I want to delete the lines without loosing the numbers

[image: curly line on image]

This is the image using the threshold method

[image: image use theshold method]

I’m using opencv for image processing and tesseract 4.0 for recoginize the text

Any hint or some sense of direction will be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried applying erosion after thresholding?

Comment: problems like this are best solved using tailored classifiers. Using higher image resolution and less compression would also help a lot.

Comment: @user2986898 yes, i tried but it lose stroke of number. thank for your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried multiple approaches. The following one is the closest I could get to.

[image]

Simple Algorithm:

1. Obtain green channel of the image
2. Apply Gaussian blur of kernel size (3x3)
3. Apply histogram equalization
4. Find a suitable threshold to get the desired result

This is just a starter. You can get far better result if you incorporate adaptive threshold techniques and morphological operations.

(I have the code available in case you need it)

Comment: I am having a similar challenge. Can you please share the code if available?

Comment: @SrijanSharma I'm sorry, this was written more than 2 years ago on my old laptop